# MyBatis Batch Update Exception:Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

Blow is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` 
(   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR}(255) NOT NULL,
    `priority` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Below is my SQL file

```
<update id="batchUpdate"> 
UPDATE user  <trim prefix="SET" suffixOverrides=",">  
<trim prefix="username=CASE" suffix="END,">
<foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=" ">
 <if test="item.username!=null">WHEN id=#{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT} THEN #{item.username,jdbcType=VARCHAR}</if>
 </foreach>
</trim>
<trim prefix="priority=CASE" suffix="END,">
<foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=" ">
  <if test="item.priority!=null">WHEN id=#{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT} THEN #{item.priority,jdbcType=BIGINT}</if>
</foreach>
</trim>  
</trim>
WHERE id IN  
<foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" open="(" close=")" separator=",">#{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
 </foreach>
</update>
```

Below is my update data:

```
user1{ id:1, username:"test1", priority:1 } 
user2{ id:1, priority:3 }
```

When I update user1 and user2 together using batchUpdate, I got exception below:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: ### Error
>   updating database.  Cause:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'priority' cannot be null### The error may involve
>   defaultParameterMap### The error occurred while setting parameters###
>   SQL: SET username=CASE WHEN id=? THEN ? END,    priority=CASE WHEN
>   id=? THEN ?  WHEN id=? THEN ? END, WHERE id IN( ?,?)### Cause:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'username' cannot be null; SQL []; Column 'cspuid' cannot be
>   null; nested exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'cspuid' cannot be null    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:85)   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) at
>   org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)    at
>   org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365)   at
>   $Proxy8.update(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:251) at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)  at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40) at
>   $Proxy69.batchUpdateByKey(Unknown Source)

While the SQL Logger print the SQL below which could be executed success in mysql:SQL:

```
UPDATE user SET username=CASE WHEN id=2 THEN 'test1' END, priority=CASE WHEN id=2 THEN 3 WHEN id=1 THEN 1 END WHERE id IN ( 2 , 1 )
```

While I update user1 and user2 dividually, it update them success. And if I change user1 and user2 as blew, it don't throw exception too. It seems that the update colummns should be same in update data List.

```
user1{ id:1, priority:1 } user2{ id:1, priority:3 }
```

The issue is very weird, because the SQL print could be executed success in mysql. It's problem about MyBatis?

Another batch update method like below. It's simple but it always return 1/0, don't return row(s)affected. Have any good methods to get count of rows affected?

```
<update id="batchUpdate"> 
<foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=";">
UPDATE user  <trim prefix="SET" suffixOverrides=",">  
 <if test="item.username!=null">username=#{item.username,jdbcType=VARCHAR}</if>
 <if test="item.priority!=null">priority=#{item.priority,jdbcType=BIGINT}</if>
WHERE id=#{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
 </foreach>
</update>
```

Comment: i can't edit this there are like no line breaks

Comment: yes, it's messy. I format it just now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<update id="batchUpdate">
  UPDATE user 
    SET 
    username = CASE
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=" "> 
      <if test="item.username!=null">
        WHEN id = #{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT} THEN #{item.username,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
      </if>
    </foreach>
    ELSE username
    END
    ,
    priority = CASE
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=" ">     
      <if test="item.priority!=null">
        WHEN id = #{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT} THEN #{item.priority,jdbcType=BIGINT}
      </if>    
    </foreach>
    ELSE priority
    END
    WHERE id IN 
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
      #{item.id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    </foreach>
</update>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I'm curious about why `ELSE` is neccessary. Without `ELSE` the sql generated by mybatis from mapper file actually can execute in mysql. SQL printed by Logger: `UPDATE user SET username=CASE WHEN id=2 THEN 'test1' END, priority=CASE WHEN id=2 THEN 3`.  I wonder why.

Comment: (a bit late, but I want to clarify) In this example the `ELSE` statement is not necessary. It would be necessary without the `WHERE id IN ...`

Comment: Guys, without else statements in some conditions can be like: "UPDATE user SET username=CASE END, priority=CASE END WHERE id IN (1,2,3)" which is depending on mysql configuration may cause invalid query failures, cuz it will not know what to update. To have syntactically correct UPDATE query in my example I return the current parameter as else state. MySQL by itself will not change anything if field values are same, that's ok.